# AJAX returning 404

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I am trying to send JSON from Twig template to PHP class, that will save in it database, but I keed getting 404 error.

This is content of my twig template. My targetis to send this commented off `data` var, but for testing purposes I replaced it.

```
function saveUser()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("subject_select");
    var subject = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log(subject);

    var e2 = document.getElementById("mark_select");
    var mark = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(mark);

    var e3 = document.getElementById("student_select");
    var student = e3.options[e3.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(student);

    //var data = ({ subject:subject, mark:mark, student:student}).serialize();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'save/',
            data: {subject:"a", mark:1, student:2},
            success: function(response)
            {
               console.log(response);
            }
          });
```

and class in php:

```
class TestMark extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/save/", name="_save")
     */
    public function saveAction(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", null, "school");
            /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
        }
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {//no ajax request, no play...
            $this->redirect(
                $this->generateUrl('_gradebook')
            );
        }
        $jsonString = $this->getRequest();
        $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
        /* create a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO marks (studentId, mark, subject) VALUES (?,?,?)')) {
            /* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $jsonArray['subject'], $jsonArray['mark'], $jsonArray['student']);
            /* execute query */
            $stmt->execute();
            /* close statement */
            $stmt->close();
        }
        /* close connection */
        $mysqli->close();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After some changes I'm getting error 500 with such log from Chrome console:

```
GET http://host/save/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
l.cors.b.crossDomain.send @ jquery.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
saveUser @ gradebook:66
onclick @ gradebook:125
```

JS and ajax:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ path('_save') }}" id="save_url">
        <script>

            function saveUser()
            {
                var requestUrl = $('#save_url').val();

                var e = document.getElementById("subject_select");
                var subject = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                console.log(subject);

                var e2 = document.getElementById("mark_select");
                var mark = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
                console.log(mark);

                var e3 = document.getElementById("student_select");
                var student = e3.options[e3.selectedIndex].value;

                //var data = ({ subject:subject, mark:mark, student:student }).serialize();
                console.log(student);

                $.post('{{path('AppBundle_ajax_update')}}',
                        {subject: 'mydata1', mark:'mydata2', student:'mydata3'},
                        function(response){
                            if(response.code == 100 && response.success){//dummy check
                           //do something
                            }
                        }, "json");
            }
```

MarkController.php:

```
class MarkController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/save/", name="_save")
     */
    public function saveAction(){

        $request = $this->container->get('request');

        $mark = new Mark();
        $mark->setSubject($request->query->get('subject'));
        $mark->setMark($request->query->get('mark'));
        $mark->setStudent($request->query->get('student'));

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($mark);
        $em->flush();

        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true);
        return new Response(json_encode($response));
    }
}
```

Comment: note: your bind statement says 4 parameters (`ssss`), but you only provide 3 values, and only have 3 paceholders in the query.

Comment: What happens if you change `url: 'save/',` to `url: '/save/',` in your ajax call?

Comment: You should read the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html).

Comment: Still nothing without this placeholder, and with /save/ instead of save/.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Rename your **Controller** class

```
TestMark
```

**to**

```
TestMarkController
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller isn't returning any response. Try returning:

```
return new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response('student saved');
```

after you close the mysql connection.

I also recommend getting the request url on the twig template. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ path('_save') }}" id="save_url">
```

Then, in your js:

```
var requestUrl = $('#save_url').val();

$.ajax({
    ...
    url: requestUrl,
    ...
});
```

And as suggested by Imanali Mamadiev, you should rename your controller class.

Comment: you can get all the urls in your symfony2 app by running `php bin/console debug:router`

Comment: Yeah, I made progress. Now it returns 500 Internal Server Error
`l.cors.b.crossDomain.send @ jquery.min.js:4


n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4


saveUser @ gradebook:67


onclick @ gradebook:114`

Comment: are you requesting in debug mode? like /app_dev.php/_save? What's the request url?

Comment: try `app_dev.php/save/` and you should get an error

Comment: I corrected some error, and now there's only one caused by null in query. But it still doesn't work.
Updated class code once more

Comment: Please query the ajax request to http://host/app_dev.php/save/ to get some error information